# Socket.io communicating from server to client not happening

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

i am trying to do a very simple real time notification with socket.io. for some reason i can't receive data or fire the event from server to client but from client to server yes. let me show my code:

**Client Side**

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.socket.on('connect', function (res: any) {
        console.log('Socket.io is connected on client side!'); // it shows on client console
    });

    this.socket.on('alarmsreceived', function (res: any) {
        console.log(res + ' i am here now'); // is not firing 
    });

}

   // this method fires from a click button
   objectStatus = () => {

    this.socket.emit('alarmsystem', 'i am client going to server');

}
```

**Server**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var connections = [];

io.of('/api/v1/monitoring').on('connect', function(socket){
connections.push(socket);
console.log('Connected %s sockets', connections.length); // i see connection on cmd

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log('Connected %s sockets', connections.length);
});

socket.on('alarmsystem', function(res) {
    console.log(res); // this shows me the message from client
    io.sockets.emit('alarmsreceived', 'I am server heading to client');
});
})
```

it seems pretty straight forward, but not firing the client event. Can someone help me what i am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this.socket.emit get called? Does io.sockets.emit get called on server?

Comment: You can try io.emit instead of io.sockets.emit does that work?